# JAVAHL (JNI) Not available

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-indigo

Windows 7 64 Bits, Eclipse Indigo, SlickSVN 1.6.17 all installed with path to the libraries entered in windows.

Why do I get the message JAVAHL (JNI) Not available and why does eclipse not load these libraries?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried installing SilkSVN as suggested on the [subclipse official](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-505552e42290e459bdf53bdaa8ebda3994b21cad) FAQ?
Then on Eclipse/MyEclipse go to **Window>Preferences>Team>SVN** Change the client to **SVNKit v1.XXX**.

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you close down Eclipse before running the SlikSVN 64 bit installation?

I had the same issue initially.
Close Eclipse, rerun the SlikSVN install, choose Repair Installation.
Once complete, open Eclipse, and then you should have the "JavaHL Slik SVN" option under Window/Preferences/team/SVN

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It turns out that [the FAQ](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-505552e42290e459bdf53bdaa8ebda3994b21cad) is helpful indeed, because:

> As of the Subclipse 1.8.x releases, native 64-bit Windows binaries are
>   included with Subclipse so it includes everything you need. For
>   earlier releases of Subclipse follow these instructions:
>
> If you are using a 32-bit JVM, then Subclipse should just work. If you
>   use a 64-bit JVM then you need to provide a 64-bit version of JavaHL.
>   One such distribution is SlikSVN which you can get here:
>   http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download
>
> With that package installed, Subclipse should find JavaHL on PATH and
>   just work.

The key here is the **PATH** variable. In my case I had another svn client installed that came before in the path. When I changed to `C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\` be the **first folder** in the variable, all worked.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Uninstall existing subclipse plugin:**

[Uninstall subclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDCLE.png)

**2) Download these three files:**

- [subclipse-4.3.0.zip](https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/:subclipse-4.3.0.zip)
- [subclipse-javahl-1.12.0.zip](https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/javahl/:subclipse-javahl-1.12.0.zip)
- [subclipse.javahl.update-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT.zip](https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/javahl/:subclipse.javahl.update-1.12.0-SNAPSHOT.zip)

**3) Install them manually one by one by following theses instructions:**

http://www.microfocus.co.jp/manuals/ED23/html/GUID-70E8158C-8618-4228-9495-6AFF4CB7E8DB.html

**Ω) If not suitable in your case:**

Install this: [Subversive-4.0.2.I20160902-1700.zip](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/subversive/4.0/builds/neon/Subversive-4.0.2.I20160902-1700.zip&mirror_id=1099) (works with eclipse 2019-06)

Answer (score 0):

Now I can find **"JavaHl Slik SVN"** under SVN Interface. The solution was to uninstall **Subclipse** and to reinstall it. When reinstalling Subclipse, I removed the check on **"javahl client adapter (required)"** (or similar).