# subversion issue with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

I have recently configured eclipse for subversion by installing the plug-in subclipse. Now the problem is that when I try to import folders from svn I get this error:

> Folder " does not exist remotely

The url that I provide is of the form "svn:// ... " and works fine with netbeans. Infact I was using netbeans until now and things were fine as far as svn was concerned. Another thing is that eclipse works fine if I try to import from a test url that I got from a website during subclipse installation. So eclipse can import projects from http://subclipse.tigris.org/svn/subclipse but throws the above error for my url(which is otherwise ok with netbeans). I am using ubuntu 11.04 if that is of any concern.

Thanks for any help,

Comment: Are you importing the correct URL (no spaces)?

Answer (score 6):

I had also the same problem. But now it is working fine.

### Solution

Window->Preferences->Team->SVN

Then select 'SVN Interface' as 'JavaHL'.
Click 'Apply' and then 'OK'.

Thats it...

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!

Comment: I had message "JavaHL (JNI) Not Available" and had to also follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13053341/669645

Comment: I did the exact opposite. Mine was set to JavaHL and I switched it to SVNKit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has this problem, check the option by proxy connectivity. Set it to manual.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the IBM RAD then please  select

Window->Preferences->Team->SVN
Then select 'SVN Interface' as 'SVNKit(Pure Java)svnkIT'. Click 'Apply' and then 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported your project into the same directory under Netbeans and Eclipse? If so that might be the problem, try to use a different location.

Comment: it throws the error before asking for location, after pasting the url I am asked for user/pass, after I enter my credentials, it throws the error (my user/pass are correct, I've double checked them)

Comment: not sure it makes much difference, but I always use Checkout, not import